# MIFARE DESFire Keys issue

Tags: authentication, cryptography, smartcard, mifare

I have Mifare DESFire EV1 with 4Kb of memory. I have created an application with AID "000001". I want to authenticate with key number 1. However, I get "no such key" error code.

So probably I don't know the key inside the card, right? So how can I find out the keys? Should I contact the vendor?

Answer (score 2):

"No such key" means that the key number specified is invalid.

DESFire keys are numbered from zero. Are you sure you created the application with the correct number of keys (i.e. at least two)?

To authenticate with the application master key, use key number 0.

The initial key value is defined by the card settings. The default value is written in the manual.

Comment: Yes, I have authenticate already with application master key(Key number 0).I want to know about the initial key value which is store in the card.

Comment: As far as I know all initial key values should be the same. So If you successfully authenticated with the AMK the same key value should be valid for the other keys.

Comment: Are you sure you created the application with the correct number of keys? Are you sure you actually selected the application?